# More problems with JPA deletion of row in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following code that defines the relationship between three tables.

```
public class Attachment implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name="attachment_id")
    private int attachmentId;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="reference_id")
  private Reference reference;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="attachment")
    private List<Reference> references;

  MORE STUFF;
}

public class Uuid implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column("name=uuid_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int uuidId;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="reference_id")
  private Reference reference;

  MORE STUFF
}

public class Reference implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name="reference_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int referenceId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="reference")
  private List<Attachment> attachments;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinColumn(name="attachment_id")
  private Attachment attachment;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="reference")
  private List<Uuid> uuids;

  MORE STUFF
}
```

I have some more code that picks the specific "uuid" object/row that needs to be deleted, and the idea is that anything in the other tables that needs deleting because they share the same reference_id should be deleted too. The code that does this is:

```
try {
  final EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

  transaction.begin();
  em.remove(data);
  transaction.commit();
} catch (final PersistenceException e) {
   throw new CPDPersistenceException(e);
}
```

When the delete is performed it throws Exception "Cannot delete or update parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. I posted something on a variation of this before. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is `data` in your snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You have one one-to-many relationship between `Reference` and `Attachment` defined but also a many-to-one between `Reference` and `Attachment` (and vice versus), this will never work. You should have either one of them, not both, or a many-to-many relationship.

Fix that and it should be much easier to delete objects.

For instance:

```
public class Attachment implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name="attachment_id")
  private int attachmentId;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="reference_id")
  private Reference reference;

  //MORE STUFF;
}

public class Reference implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name="reference_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int referenceId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="reference")
  private List<Attachment> attachments;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="reference")
  private List<Uuid> uuids;

  /bMORE STUFF
}
```